# How to find the row Id using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Guys I asked a similar question like this earlier since I was unable to solve my problem I decided to ask a detailed question.Please referrer to my image

[image: Table, containing input fields]

As i mentioned on the image I need to identify the particular **table row index value or the number of the index field** to enable the particular capacity,unit price,qty fields and to display the subtotal.I tried some javascript and jq table row detection codes and they do the job but they effect to the capacity selection field baldly since every time a click or a select occurs capacity field gets reset to blank.

I tried this 2 full days but still unable to make a solution :(

This is the complete code set - http://jsfiddle.net/Ceylo/AE2Mb/

Please help me to get through this.

Comment: Could you give an exmaple for the row name? is it in a pattern? could you post some sample html maybe?

Comment: HTML code and the jQuery code you are currently working with would be helpful.

Comment: Also, could you check and fix the spelling at "but they effects to the capacity selection field baldly" please.

Comment: You were probably told last time that table row elements have a [*rowIndex* property](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6986576). Once you have the row, get its *rowIndex*.

Comment: @Kissaki,@RobG

I updated the question with the link to my code set.Please have a look at that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Supposing you put this as a callback of `$('td').click()`:

```
$(this).parent().find('td:first').text()
```

or

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text()
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6N9QR/) sample

Comment: but this will only find the first row... I didn't think it was specified?

Comment: @James Khoury: it will find `id` number specified in the first column. That is what OP wanted (at least I think that he wanted that ;-) )

Comment: @James Khoury:
Yes this is working perfectly but the problem with this is capacity select list stops working.It doesn't hold the selected item it just become white space.

var capacity=document.getElementById('cap'+row);  
capacity.innerHTML="<option> </option><option> 2GB </option><option> 4GB </option>";

Comment: @ceylo after the line `var capacity=document.getElementById('cap'+row);` add `var selection = capacity.selectedIndex;` then after `capacity.innerHTML="<option> </option><option> 2GB </option><option> 4GB </option>";` add ` capacity.selectedIndex = selection;`. You really should specify this is the problem in the question.

Comment: @James Khoury

Yes it's working thank you friend.But why it happens James?.Why it resets the selected item? can you explain it a bit?.

Thank you again.

Comment: @ceylo because you are removing the already selected option when you replace the `innerHTML` attribute so the previously selected option does not exist anymore. It should also be noted that if the number of options change this might cause an issue also.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably more elegant ways to do it, but why not just add an id that contains the row index to each tr element? You're creating them dynamically, so just use a counter to assign the id as you create them.

Comment: He obviously already has a counter, because he counts down for the first column.

Comment: Thank you user,

But my problem is not the assigning my problem is to identify the field.I have assigned id names like "field_id"+index and the index flows like 1,2,3...etc.

I need to find "Which is the field id of the changed input?".

Comment: It sounds like you want to wire up an event to the change handler for your inputs then. When the change event fires, just check the parent tr id to determine which row you're in. Or am I still not understanding your question correctly?

Comment: Rest of the code >
var item_cat,item=document.getElementById("form_items"+row).value;  
 if(item=="UD-05" || item=="PD-71" || item=="MicroSD" || item=="SD"){
          item_cat="flash";
          
      }
      else if(item=="E-HDD"){
          item_cat="ehdd";
      };
     var capacity=document.getElementById('cap'+row); 
     var price=document.getElementById('form_price'+row); 
 if(item_cat=="flash"){ 
         capacity.disabled=false;                
         price.disabled=false;                             
         capacity.innerHTML="<option> </option><option> 2GB </option>"; 
     }

Answer (score 0):

You can just use jQuery on the click or change event to navigate to the first row relative to the textarea, for example.

So if your markup is this:

```
<tr>
 <td> Row # </td>
 ...
 <td><input type="text" /></td>
</tr>
```

You could use this (pseudocode)

```
$(input).click(function() {
    var me = $(this),
    index = parseInt(me.getParent().children()[0].innerHTML);
  })
```

Notice how the navigation works, when a click event is caught on the textbox then "this" will reference the text box. So you can navigate to its parent, (the tr), then navigate to the tr's first child (the td with the row number), and get its innerHTML, an cast it to an int.

Answer (score 0):

in the case you want to identify it on change of an element :

```
jQuery("#myselect").change(function(){
    var tableBody = jQuery(this).closest("tbody"); // Find the parent table body tag
    var thisrow = jQuery(this).closest("tr"); // Find the parent row tag

    var rowid = tableBody.children().index(thisRow);
    alert(rowid);
 });
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JE8kR/

**UPDATE**

Going with RobG's advice:

```
jQuery("#myselect").change(function(){
    var thisrow = jQuery(this).closest("tr"); // Find the parent row tag

    alert(thisrow.eq(0).rowIndex);
 });
```

Comment: Once you have *thisrow* as a jQuery object, then `rowid = thisrow[0].rowIndex;` is the rowIndex.

Comment: @robG rowIndex? I like that but I've never heard of it, its not an IE only property is it?

Comment: @RobG Don't worry I answered my own question: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html apparently it works well on all browsers except opera at the time of this test.

Comment: James - much better to reference the [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-6986576).

Answer (score 0):

check this. hope that it can help:

http://jsfiddle.net/chukhanhvan/pSjHc/1/

Comment: Please convert the code into a real answer. Don't host it on an external site!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example - does most that you want it to do. For the brevity I omitted handling default select of the product etc - So if you select a "Select" option for product you will get an error. Ideally you would do this using some sort of template and render product options based on your data struct as well...

on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Michal/Nubqj/

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>Table Rows</title>
        <script>
            $(document).ready( function() {



                //you need some sort of data struct if price and capacity varies per product
                inventory  = [{
                    name:"Product 1",
                    capacities:[{
                        "cap":4,
                        "price": 39.95
                    },{
                        "cap":8,
                        "price": 49.95
                    },{
                        "cap":16,
                        "price": 59.95
                    }]

                },{
                    name:"Product 2",
                    capacities:[{
                        "cap":32,
                        "price": 19.95
                    },{
                        "cap":64,
                        "price": 29.95
                    },{
                        "cap":128,
                        "price": 39.95
                    }]

                }]
                var parentEl; //element which will hold your row DOM reference

                $(".prod").change( function() {
                    html = "";

                    productIndex =this.selectedIndex-1

                    //build the appropriate capacity dropdown
                    for (i = 0;i<inventory[productIndex].capacities.length;i++){
                        html += "<option value='"+inventory[productIndex].capacities[i].price+"'>"+inventory[productIndex].capacities[i].cap+"</option>";
                    }
                    //find the row to update

                    parentEl = $(this).closest("tr");


                    capacity = parentEl.find(".capacity")
                //update capacity dropdown  and append html
                    capacity.html(html)
                    //enable capacity dropdown
                    capacity.attr("disabled",false)
                    //i am assuming that initialy the price will be the price of the first element in the capacity list
                    price = inventory[productIndex].capacities[0].cap;
                    //update the price column
                    parentEl.find(".price").attr("disabled", false).val(price);
                    //do the total - in this case you might want to calculate the total based on qty - I will leave it up to you to implement
                    parentEl.find(".total").text(price);
                })
                //update the price based on capacity
                $(".capacity").change(function(){
                        parentEl = $(this).closest("tr");
                        //which product are we looking at
                        productIndex = parentEl.find(".prod").selectedIndex;
                        capIndex = this.selectedIndex-1;
                        //you can find the price either from your data struct 
                        //price = inventory[productIndex].capacities[capIndex].cap;
                        //..or a value of a select
                        price = $(this).val();
                        parentEl.find(".price").attr("disabled", false).val(price);
                })
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Items</td>
                <td>Capacity</td>
                <td>Price</td>
                <td>Total</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <select class="prod">
                    <option value="">Select..</option>
                    <option value="">Product 1</option>
                    <option value="">Product 2</option>
                </select>
                </td>
                                <td>
                <select class="capacity" disabled="">

                </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" disabled="" class="price">
                </td>
                <td>
                <span class="total">-</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <select class="prod">
                            <option value="">Select..</option>
                    <option value="">Product 1</option>
                    <option value="">Product 2</option>
                </select>
                </td>
                                                <td>
                <select class="capacity" disabled="">

                </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" disabled="" class="price">
                </td>
                <td>
                <span class="total">-</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the relevant part of your code is here:

```
>     $(function() {
>       $('td').change(function() {
>         var row = $(this).parent().find('td:first').text();
>         //alert(row);
```

Within the function, *this* should be a TD element, its parent TR will be its *parentNode*. To get the *rowIndex* you just need:

```
var rowIndex = this.parentNode.rowIndex;
```